# Spring RESTful API not accepting XML params - Java

Tags: xml, spring, spring-rest

I am using Postman to post some data in XML on a restful API, but it gives,

```
Required String parameter 'username' is not present
```

here is the action,

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getToken", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String,String> getToken(@RequestParam("username")String username, @RequestParam("password")String password)
```

the XML I am sending is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<username>someone@gmail.com</username>
<password>qweQWE123!@#</password>
</root>
```

I am guessing the part where I am accepting the parameters (@RequestParam("username")String username, @RequestParam("password")String password) is the issue, to fix it I replaced it with,

```
@RequestBody XMLObject object
```

But then "Not Acceptable" error appeared.

Comment: The first thing I would check if XMLObject object is filled in, in other words not null. If it is null you're probably missing a xml serializer on your classpath. Because a Not Acceptable (406) response implies that spring was unable to serializer the Map<String,String> to the correct type according to your accept header.

Comment: Are you setting the content type correctly in your POST request?